# 2 SPI devices conflict

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, ethernet

I want to connect a W5500 ethernet Module and an SD card module to arduino Uno using SPI (with different CS pins of course). When connected separately they work fine but when connected in the same circuit the ethernet module doesn't get a correct ip address and always gets an address 255.255.255.255. To me the ethernet module is the likely culprit as the SD card module works without problem even when the ethernet module is also connected.

Tried using Ethernet & Ethernet2 libraries but no difference. Tried manually assigning the IP address but it won't work. I have even set the CS pins HIGH in the setup before calling SD.begin & Ethernet.begin() to avoid both components "listening" at the same time but it still doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Here is the sketch I am working with. Although it doesn't use SD module but as mentioned above if SD module is connected in the circuit, ethernet module doesn't get incorrect ip address

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>

//IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 22);


// MAC address just has to be unique. This should work
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

EthernetServer server(80);

void setup()
{

  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); // SD module CS
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // Ethernet module CS
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delay(1);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("Server started on: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop()
{
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client)
  {
    while (client.connected())
    {
      // send a standard http response header
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      client.println();

      // send the body
      client.println("<html><body>");
      client.println("<h1>Arduino Server</h1>");
      client.print("<p>A0=");
      client.print(analogRead(0));
      client.println("</p>");
      client.print("<p>millis=");
      client.print(millis());
      client.println("</p>");
      client.println("</body></html>");
      client.stop();
    }
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

Another sketch with reference to both SD and Ethernet Libraries

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SD.h>

byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0xC3, 0xA2, 0xE6, 0x3D, 0x57 };
byte LED = 2;
char wServer[] = "media.wizards.com";
char wFile[] = "/images/magic/tcg/resources/rules/MagicCompRules_20140601.pdf";

EthernetClient myClient;

void setup() {
  //D53 on an Arduino Mega must be an output.
  pinMode(53, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.print("Establishing network connection... ");

  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("FAILED!");
    while (true) {
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      delay(500);
    }
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("OK!");
  }
}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(wServer);
  Serial.print("... ");

  if (myClient.connect(wServer, 80) == 1) {
    Serial.println("OK!");

    myClient.print("GET ");
    myClient.print(wFile);
    myClient.println(" HTTP/1.0");
    myClient.print("Host: ");
    myClient.println(wServer);
    myClient.println();

    if (SD.begin(8)) {
      if (SD.exists("MAGIC.PDF"))
        SD.remove("MAGIC.PDF");

      Serial.print("Saving response... ");
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);

      File dd = SD.open("MAGIC.PDF", FILE_WRITE);

      char lc;
      while (myClient.connected()) {
        if (myClient.available()) {
          char nc = myClient.read();
          if ((lc == 10) && (nc == 13)) {
            while (myClient.available() == 0);
            myClient.read();
            break;
          }
          else
            lc = nc;
        }
      }

      while (myClient.connected()) {
        if (myClient.available() > 0) {
          dd.write(myClient.read());
        }
      }

      dd.close();
      delay(500);
      Serial.println("OK");
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    }
    else
      Serial.println("No SD card detected!");

    myClient.stop();
  } 
  else
    Serial.println("FAILED!");

  delay(3600000);
  asm volatile(" jmp 0");
```

Comment: Where did you tell the SD library  and the Ethernet library which CS they should use?

Comment: In additional to @theSealion very valid question. This [article](https://www.pjrc.com/better-spi-bus-design-in-3-steps/) should be able to help you to troubleshoot and narrow down the cause.

Comment: [ethernet2.h](https://github.com/adafruit/Ethernet2) is deprecated.

Comment: ethernet2 by default using pin 10 as cs (https://github.com/adafruit/Ethernet2/blob/master/src/utility/w5500.h#L133), however, your code has no reference to SD card library or initialisation of SD card.

Comment: I have experimented with a few different sketches but it's not working. I have uploaded another sketch which I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: @theSealion the ethernet library by default uses pin 10 as cspin so no need to mention it. As I mention in my original post, by keeping both SD card module and ethernet module in the circuit causes an issue. It doesn't matter if the sketch has reference to SD library or not. Since in my circuit, the sd module has pin 8 as CSpin and that I pulled high to avoid any conflict but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Zaffresky than I would recommend to start looking at the hardware. Take a voltage meter and have a look at the CS and SPI lines when the µC is in reset state and when your sketch is running. Even better would be a oscilloscope to watch the signal.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my SD card module.

I don't have too much knowledge about all details, but it is related that most SD card modules (the simple ones) do not have tri-state functionality, meaning they cannot cope with multiple SPI devices on the same bus.

Sadly, the Arduino has only one SPI connection, but there are solutions:

- There exist tri-state buffers which you can use  (somewhere in the CD or 74HC range). See comment of hcheung: use e.g. an 74AHC125  MISO tri-state buffer.
- However, another solution is to use e.g. an SD card shield, something like https://boutique.semageek.com/en/1445-sd-storage-shield-with-rtc-clock-for-arduino.html

[image]

Comment: I think you are referring to [74AHC125](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/74AHC125.pdf) to be used a MISO tri-state buffer.

Comment: @hcheung yes, thanks ... I will add it to the answer

Comment: The problem with SD cards is that the SD card doesn't strictly adhere to the SPI protocol standards.  The CS pin doesn't cause the SD card to be isolated from the bus as it should, and there are specific operations that you perform on a SD card through the SPI bus while the CS pin is held high.

Comment: Also the order of initialization is critical. You must start the SD card before any other SPI device to ensure that every device on the bus is SPI, since the SD card defaults to SDIO mode and that can interfere with the rest of the bus.

Comment: @Majenko am I right that a tri-state buffer like 74AHC125 will fix the CS pin problem?

Comment: It certainly helps matters, yes. When the SD is isolated from the bus then no matter what it does it can't interfere with the rest of the bus.

Comment: Personally I never share the SPI bus with anything else when using an SD card (but then I use PIC32 with multiple SPI busses). If needed you can always bit-bang SPI for other devices that don't need high speed.

Comment: @Majenko good to know thanks ... haven't used an SD card for long but found the problem when I started with Arduino, to be honest, never tried the buffer (since I was just trying out lots of stuff).

Comment: @Majenko Also one reason for trying to use STM32 is they have indeed more features (like more SPIs, and especially more SRAM).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Meh... if you like ARM, sure... Give me MIPS any day though ;)

Comment: @Majenko can you give an example of MIPS microcontrollers? (or am I missing something)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers PIC32. It's all I use unless I have to use something else due to a customer requirement.

Comment: @Majenko somehow it's not really advertised or so ... I mean I checked Arduino, found it to be too limiting for what I wanted (learning microcontrollers), and the most 'obvious' links where STM32(F1). So I don't know how good/bad PIC32 (probably good as professionals use it). But I'm a bit doubtful to move (again) to a different architecture.

Comment: Heh. PIC32 has the advantage that it gets the best hardware/software support from me ;) chipKIT is the Arduino API variant for PIC32, though it is slightly lagging behind on some of the API facilities.

Comment: @Majenko I will check into it (because I'm curious).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Thanks for the info but I wonder if the SD card shield also uses the SPI bus? If so then how will it be different than using the SD card module?

Comment: @Majenko I don't know anything about that tristate buffer but will read more about it. Also will need to order first the 74AHC125 ic to test it

Comment: @Majenko I tried initiating the SD card prior to start the ethernet but still it fails. I guess it more of a hardware issue and the tristate buffer thing will probably fix it. What really surprises me is that even if I pull the CSpin of the SD card high throughout the sketch, the ethernet module isn't able to get the correct ip so keeping it's CS pin high has no effect at all?